# How do you go to a specific record chosen from a listbox and displayed on the navigation form?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a navigation form which has a `subform` with a `recordsource tblA`.
Currently, the `subform` displays the specific record in popup window. Is it possible for it to display the record in the navigation form without having to pop up?

```
Private Sub Search_Change()
    Dim where As String

    Const SQLResults As String = "SELECT itemNumber, itemName FROM tblMain "
    <whereclause> ORDER BY ItemName;"

    If Me.Search.Text <> "" Then
        where = "WHERE itemName LIKE '*" & Me.Search.Text & "*' "
    End If

    Me.SearchResults.RowSource = Replace(SQLResults, "<whereclause>", where)

End Sub
```

The below code displays the record in a pop-up window.

```
Private Sub SearchResults_Click()

    Dim searchCriteria As String

    searchCriteria = "[itemNumber]='" & Me![SearchResults].Value & "'"

    DoCmd.OpenForm "frmDisplay", acNormal, , searchCriteria
    DoCmd.Close acForm, "frmSearch"

End Sub
```

Since form `frmNavigation` is always open:

```
Private Sub SearchResults_Click()
    DoCmd.OpenForm, "frmDisplay", acNormal, , searchCritera
    DoCmd.Close acForm, "frmSearch"
End Sub
```

Can someone help?

Comment: What about using filter?

Comment: I have changed the forms pup up behaviour in the forms property tab to no but it still opens in opening the record in a different tab.

Comment: @Lee Mac any direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done it! I hope this solution helps someone. The code allows the user to select the item in a listbox on a pop-up form and takes the user to that same record on the navigation form. It makes the forms operation simpler without popping up the subform. Note: You do not need to set pop-up feature on the property sheet to false. It will work regardless.

```
Private Sub SearchResults_Click()
  Dim searchCriteria As String
  Dim rs As Recordset

  searchCriteria = "[itemNo]='" & Me![SearchResults].Value & "'"
  Set rs = Forms!frmNavigation!NavigationSubform.Form.RecordsetClone
  rs.FindFirst searchCriteria
  If Not rs.NoMatch Then Forms!frmNavigation!NavigationSubform.Form.Bookmark = rs.Bookmark
  Forms!frmNavigation!NavigationSubform.Form.Filter = "[itemNo]=" & Me.SearchResults.Value
  Me.FilterOn = True
  Set rs = Nothing

  DoCmd.Close acForm, "frmSearch"
 End Sub
```